# Express - Create a new view engine

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, viewengine

I know that expressjs supports many view engines, like: ejs, jade, etc. I saw a list here: http://expressjs-book.com/forums/topic/how-to-use-alternative-non-jade-template-engines-with-express/.

My question is how can I create my own view engine. I've looked in ejs and in other engines' source-code but I didn't really find an expressjs documentation on how to create a new engine, what are the requirements, or a tutorial about it.

Is it possible to create a new custom view engine? Thanks.

Comment: `Is it possible to create a new custom view engine?`


Of course, it was done many times. Basically, view engine is some sort of HTML compiler. You could compare view engines with JavaScript or CSS preprocessors, e.g. CoffeeScript/TypeScript or Less/Sass. You would need some knowledge on how compilers work if you want your view engine to be effective. But I don't know why would you go through the trouble, there are already enough view engines out there so why would you reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#templating) list for templating engines.

Regarding express itself, what you need to do is create a plugin, or even a middleware function - that will attach your `render`, `renderFile` and similar methods to the response object.

If you don't use an express engine and try to, say, `response.render('index.ejs');`, you'll get an error. But if that response object has a render method, you're fine. So it boils down to extending expresses' response object with what you need.